# How to filter out keys and values based on value in a map scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code that reformats a Json object into another Json object:

```
 val newJson = Json.toJson(retJson.fields.flatMap {
      case (epoch, obj) => obj.as[JsObject].fields.map(epoch -> _)
    }.groupBy(_._2._1)
    .mapValues(
      _.map {
        case (epoch, (k, v)) => {
          var epochDate = epoch.substring(0, 13).toLong
          epochDate = convertEpoch(epochDate, timezoneOffset)
          Seq[Double](epochDate, sensorCalculations(whatevers, Option(v.as[String])))
        }
      }))
```

This works well but we have a new requirement that when a value comes in as -1 we should ignore this element and not include it in the result.  Im not sure how to do this properly.

--- EDIT ---

I have tried the following that causes a match error

```
case (epoch, (k, v)) if v.as[String] != "-1" => {
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked for me:

```
   val il = for {
      (epoch, obj) <- retJson.fields
      (k, v) <- obj.as[JsObject].fields
      if v.as[String] != "-1"
    } yield (epoch, (k, v))

    val mapResult = il.groupBy(_._2._1)
      .mapValues(
        _.map {
          case (epoch, (k, v)) => {
            var epochDate = epoch.substring(0, 13).toLong
            epochDate = convertEpoch(epochDate, timezoneOffset)
            Seq[Double](epochDate, sensorCalculations(whatevers, Option(v.as[String])))
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if clause where appropriate. For instance value k can be checked:

```
....
case (epoch, (k, v)) if(!(k==-1))=> {
...
```

Comment: I actually have already tried this, the problem is the match is not exhaustive and ends up causing a MatchError

Answer (score 0):

```
val newJson = Json.toJson(retJson.fields.flatMap {
  case (epoch, obj) => obj.as[JsObject].fields.map(epoch -> _)
}.groupBy(_._2._1)
  .mapValues(
  _.collect {
    case (epoch, (k, v)) if v != -1 => {
      var epochDate = epoch.substring(0, 13).toLong
      epochDate = convertEpoch(epochDate, timezoneOffset)
      Seq[Double](epochDate, sensorCalculations(whatevers, Option(v.as[String])))
    }
  }))
```

Comment: I actually have already tried this, the problem is the match is not exhaustive and ends up causing a MatchError